# C# - Populate a list using lambda expressions or LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

It's been a while since I've used lambda expressions or LINQ and am wondering how I would do the following (I know I can use a foreach loop, this is just out of curiosity) using both methods.

I have an array of string paths (does it make a difference if it's an array or list here?) from which I want to return a new list of just the filenames.

i.e. using a foreach loop it would be:

```
string[] paths = getPaths();
List<string> listToReturn = new List<string>();
foreach (string path in paths)
{
    listToReturn.add(Path.GetFileName(path));
}

return listToReturn;
```

How would I do the same thing with both lambda and LINQ?

**EDIT:** In my case, I'm using the returned list as an ItemsSource for a ListBox (WPF) so I'm assuming it's going to need to be a list as opposed to an IEnumerable?

Comment: maybe there are similar questions already in SO?

Comment: Re the Edit: Yes, use a .ToList() in the last stage.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your main tool would be the .Select() method.

```
string[] paths = getPaths();
var fileNames = paths.Select(p => Path.GetFileName(p));
```

> does it make a difference if it's an array or list here?

No, an array also implements `IEnumerable<T>`

---

Note that this minimal approach involves *deferred execution*,  meaning that `fileNames` is an `IEnumerable<string>` and only starts iterating over the source array when you get elements from it.

If you want a List (to be safe), use

```
string[] paths = getPaths();
var fileNames = paths.Select(p => Path.GetFileName(p)).ToList();
```

But when there are many files you might want to go the opposite direction (get the results interleaved, faster) by also using a *deferred execution* source:

```
var filePaths = Directory.EnumerateFiles(...);  // requires Fx4
var fileNames = filePaths.Select(p => Path.GetFileName(p));
```

It depends on what you want to do next with `fileNames`.

Comment: +1 for not explicitly iterating over the result and turning it into a `List<string>`.

Comment: @Henk: no, the other upvoted post finishes with a `ToList()` call. I like the fact that your sample doesn't do that.

Comment: @Fredrik: I think when the question *explicitly requests* a list, answers should probably either create a list or say why they're not doing so.

Comment: You really can replace `p => Path.GetFileName(p)` with `Path.GetFileName`.

Comment: @Jon: you have a good point there (which I agree on; a brief explanation would be in its place), but I often see people use `List<T>` simply because they are unaware of the alternatives, so I tend to like answers that "stop in time". I am not saying that the OP is unaware of this, but there is nothing in the post indicating that there is actual need for anything that is not offered by `IEnumerable<T>` (apart from the variable declaration).

Comment: @gaearon: You're right, in this special case. I missed it but I would normally use a lambda anyway, just for tradition.

Answer (score 6):

I think by "LINQ" you really mean "a query expression" but:

```
// Query expression
var listToReturn = (from path in paths
                    select Path.GetFileName(path)).ToList();

// Extension methods and a lambda
var listToReturn = paths.Select(path => Path.GetFileName(path))
                        .ToList();

// Extension methods and a method group conversion
var listToReturn = paths.Select(Path.GetFileName)
                        .ToList();
```

Note how the last one works by constructing the projection delegate from a method group, like this:

```
Func<string, string> projection = Path.GetFileName;
var listToReturn = paths.Select(projection).ToList();
```

(Just in case that wasn't clear.)

Note that *if* you don't need to use this as a list - if you *just* want to iterate over it, in other words - you can drop the `ToList()` call from each of these approaches.

Answer (score 5):

It's just:

```
var listToReturn = getPaths().Select(x => Path.GetFileName(x)).ToList();
```

As already stated in other answers, if you don't actually need a `List<string>` you can omit the `ToList()` and simply return `IEnumerable<string>` (for example if you just need to iterate it, `IEnumerable<>` is better because avoids the creation of an other list of strings)

Also, given that `Select()` method takes a delegate, and there's an implicit conversion between method groups and delegates having the same signature, you can skip the lambda and just do:

```
getPaths().Select(Path.GetFileName)
```

Comment: There's no point in lambda when you can just pass the function. Also, I think it makes sense to state that `IEnumerable` returned by `Select` is sufficient for enumeration and list conversion may not be required.

Comment: @gaeron: yes, there's no need in using lambda. Anyway, I think that's  negligibly faster then lambda and the latter is more readable IMO. BTW, edited :)

Answer (score 4):

You could do it like this:

```
return getPaths().Select(Path.GetFileName);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
listToReturn = paths.ToList().Select(p => Path.GetFileName(p));
```